# Cheatsheet for Markdown and Restructure syntax comparision?

Tags: documentation, markdown, restructuredtext

Is there a cheatsheet that compares the usage of Markdown with Restructure? With this, I could learn `rst` faster if I already knew `Markdown`.  I tried google for it but haven't found one..

Answer (score 2):

- A small comparsion from a lot lightweight markup language syntaxs can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lightweight_markup_languages).
- There is also a [Gist document](https://gist.github.com/dupuy/1855764) about the *common markup* between the two languages.
- You can use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert your existing Markdown to reST or the other way around.
- There are a lot of different Markdown dialects, so it may be difficult to compare the syntax with reST.